# How to execute useEffect in order?

Tags: reactjs

I want to execute useEffect in order synchronously.

```
const [first, setFirst] = useState([]);
const [second, setSecond] = useState([]);
const [third, setThird] = useState([]);

function firstFunc(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    array[i] + 1;
  }
}

function secondFunc(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    array[i] + 2;
  }
}

function thirdFunc(array) {
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
    array[i] + 3;
  }
}

// 1. first useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  setFirst(firstFunc([1, 2, 3]));
}, []);

// 2. second useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  setSecond(secondFunc(first));
}, [first]);

// 3. third useEffect
useEffect(() => {
  setThird(thirdFunc(second));
}, [second]);
```

As this code, with `useEffect` I execute the first useEffect to update first state.

and once first state changes, `after that`, I want to update the second state.

`after that`, I want to update the third state.

In order to do this, I code like above with `dependency`.

But sometimes in practice it doesn't work as I expected, not in order.

Please help me what is the problem and how to achieve my goal.

Comment: Notice that each *useEffect* code block will run on firest render no matter what, so maybe that is the cause for your confusion. Another thing is you are misusing react hooks state management, you should not manipulate the arrays directly as you do, only using the setter from *useState*.

Comment: "in order asynchronously" is an oxymoron

Answer (score 0):

in your second and third `useEffect` check if your dependencies are empty or not. if not empty then execute the functions. i write the second `useEffect` code for you so you can figure out how it works.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(first.length>0){
     setSecond(secondFunc(first));
  }
  
}, [first]);
```

Comment: In this case for example, first state changes from [1, 2, 3] to [2, 3, 4] then it can't detect state change since length is longer than 0 always, isnt it?

Comment: your first state default is [] so it's length is 0 at start when the first useEffect is done then your first state is not [] so the second one will execute

Comment: Ah that's just example, so right this example can be solved with your answer but i want to know the way whatever state changes not just from [] to [1, 2] but also from [1,2,3] to [2,3,4]

Comment: instead of checking if the length is more than zero you can check if the array is not equal to it's default value. you can use for loops to achieve that